# Why is id variable not passed to this file?

Tags: php

i need to pass this id

```
 <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>">
```

in here

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id'])) { 
    $id = $_POST['id']; 
}
else { 
    echo "user not find"; 
    die(); 
}
```

its echo "user not find". why?

Comment: Try `$_GET` to see output

Comment: because you use $_GET

Comment: Change all the `$_POST` to `$_GET` - that's the answer.